Найти количество способов составить строку из символов A и B длины n, в которой нет трех подряд идущих символов B и четырех подряд идущих символов А
Длина строки n больше 0, но не больше 1000. Нужно найти количество способов составить строку длины n, где нет трёх идущих подряд В и четырёх идущих подряд А. Вывести нужно количество способ делённое на (10^9 + 7). Пробовал решить рекурсией, но если n 30 и больше, то уже очень долго решает. Других идей нет. Как можно решить эту задачу эффективно?
Вот код на C++:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i, n, spos;
long int del;
int temp;

void Count(int len, string b)
{
    if (len < n)
    {
        if (b == "B" || b == "BB")
        {
            Count(len + 1, "A");
            Count(len + 2, "AA");
            Count(len + 3, "AAA");
        }
        else if (b == "A" || b == "AA" || b == "AAA")
        {
            Count(len + 1, "B");
            Count(len + 2, "BB");
        }
    }
    else if (len == n)
    {
        spos += 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    Count(1, "B");
    Count(2, "BB");
    Count(1, "A");
    Count(2, "AA");
    Count(3, "AAA");
    del = pow(10, 9) + 7;
    cout << spos % del;
}


Ну, это вот spos % del точно не сработает :) Потому и просят по модулю, что там числа будут, грубо говоря, тысячезначные... И, кстати, очень желательно давать для таких задач URL проверяющей системы... Кстати, вы не написали, из каких букв вообще можно собирать строку. Из всего алфавита?

Я тут интереса ради посчитал, для n = 1000 таких строк 221743336594805907229956882454016777923764051153124222912134454246573401555095921571737398590353181339366686758246174620822976498100667062855300215876466288033146491634639636974005702967975216185831720617191294736163290836324101641232722477 :)

@Harry, сколько можно унижать сиплюсплюсников своими питоновскими длинными целыми? Сжальтесь, у них только короткие.

@StanislavVolodarskiy В 1001-й раз говорю: я не питоню! :) У меня к змеям идиосинкразия! Я даже не знаю, как переживу 2025 год... :)  https://bit.ly/3Ab7fAc - мне было интересно именно само число, а не по модулю... Да, кстати, этой последовательности в oeis нет, никто не хочет добавить? :)

@Harry, прошу прощения. На OEIS её не будет, потому что она получается возведением матрицы в степень. Не интересно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Там половина таких неинтересных...

Эту задачу можно решить с помощью динамического программирования вместо рекурсии. Заводите массив размером 5x1000, где пять столбцов относятся к комбинациям, которые вы уже перечислили. Инициализируете:
M[0][0] = 1;
M[0][1] = 0;
M[0][2] = 1;
M[0][3] = 0;
M[0][4] = 0;

Затем в цикле:
M[i][0] = (M[i-1][2] + M[i-1][3] + M[i-1][4]) % modulo;  //'B'
M[i][1] = M[i-1][0];                                    //'BB'
M[i][2] = (M[i-1][0] + M[i-1][1]) % modulo;            //'A'
M[i][3] = M[i-1][2];                                  //'AA'
M[i][4] = M[i-1][3];                                 //'AAA'

И результат - сумма последней заполненной строки
В общем-то, такой длинный массив не нужен, можно обойтись двумя строками, заполняя то нулевую, то первую
M[i&1][1] = M[(i+1)&1][0]; 

Для ограничения в 1000 этого хватит. Если же придётся считать для очень больших длин, то можно использовать матричный способ
(как это работает - можно посмотреть для матричного вычисления больших чисел Фибоначчи)
[Mn0]    [ 0 0 1 1 1 ]^(n-1)       [1]
[Mn1]    [ 1 0 0 0 0 ]             [0]
[Mn2] =  [ 1 1 0 0 0 ]        *    [1] 
[Mn3]    [ 0 0 1 0 0 ]             [0] 
[Mn4]    [ 0 0 0 1 0 ]             [0]

(возможно, матрицу надо транспонировать)
а возведение матрицы в степень выполняется за log(n) операций умножения матриц с помощью быстрого алгоритма (бинарное возведение в степень, пример для чисел), причем внутри умножений надо не забывать про взятие модуля.

Не удержался и набросал в олимпиадном стиле:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned mod = 1000000007;
    unsigned a = 1, aa = 0, aaa = 0, b = 1, bb = 0;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        auto ta = (b + bb) % mod;
        auto tb = (a + aa + aaa) % mod;
        aaa = aa;
        aa = a;
        bb = b;
        a = ta;
        b = tb;
    }
    std::cout << (a + b) % mod << '\n';
}

